# Hourly cron Job Excuting 60 times

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to send an email hourly using the Task scheduler in (laravel) framwork,
the command I am typing in the kernal.php:
$schedule->command('cron:activeUsers')->hourly()->withoutOverlapping();

than put the following in crontab -e:

- - - - - cd /testEmail && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

but I am getting like 60 or even 100 email instead of one,
I put some logs to see what is happening:
the cron job is excuting and sending email on the first 60 second of the first minute of each hour like the following for example:
12:00:00
12:00:01
12:00:02
12:00:03
12:00:04
12:00:05
.
.
12:00:59

how I can prevent the cron job to be excuted like this ? I want the cron job to be excuted only once each hour.
Am I using the wrong method to send the email?

Comment: add the code of your command to your question.

Comment: Would you please mention which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: @N69S

$count = Users::where('status', 'active')->count();
$body = 'Number of Active users: '.$count;
Mail::send([], [], function($message) use ($body){
         ->to('abc@gmail.com')
         ->body($body)
      });

Comment: @Ebi
Originaly the project is laravel 5.6 or 5.7

Answer (score 0):

The `schedule:run` command is *supposed* to be called every minute (as fast as CRON allows), like so:

```sh
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

Then, your `schedule()` function in `app/Console/Kernel.php` defines the interval for each of your tasks, so your `->hourly()` command should execute at the start of every hour.

If it is executing any faster than that, its likely that you somehow happen to call the scheduler more often than once a minute (multiple CRONs maybe for the same command?). Try a debug statement in the `schedule()` function in `app/Console/Kernel.php` to see that it actually executes once a minute.

When you put a debug statement inside your actual command (i.e. `'cron:activeUsers'`), *then* you should see that it runs every hour.

Comment: yes I put logs in the schedule
The schedule:run is checking and access the schedule method in kernal each (1 - 5) sec instead of 1 min.

any reason why schedule:run would try to run all my cron jobs like this?
my crontab clearly ask the schedule:run to run/check each 1 min only

Answer (score -1):

59 * * * *

repeat at [Minutes] [Hour] [Day of Month] [Which Month] [Which Week]

use the above value to do it every 60 minutes, If want to check it, you can also use https://crontab.guru/ to verify what exactly you want.

at 59, it tells to redo it every 59 minutes, plus have mentioned already there about the star astreriks for you to test and check along with the url of resource

Comment: just for info `59 * * * *` means it will trigger every hour (not every 59 minutes) **at** minute 59. like 00:59:00 then 01:59:00 then 02:59:00. it would have the same effect as setting it as `0 * * * *`

Comment: this has the same effect, I tried many cron format and all of them giving the same error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).